# How can I use custom 404 aliases using regex in nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-routing

I want to redirect a custom file based on uri when the requested file does not exist on server.
I tried these ways but none of them worked.

```
error_page 404 = @missing;
location @missing (parsed|nonparsed) {
    alias /home/something/$1;
}
```

and

```
location ~ (parsed|nonparsed) {
    try_files $uri /home/something/$1
}
```

How can I parse $uri and use an extracted string in the mirror?

Comment: BTW, if it's possible I don't want to use if statement due to problems when it's used in location context.

Comment: your regex is wrong, you need to remove the `[]` from inside the `()`, cause right now it's not matching the words `parsed` and `nonparsed` but instead the letters `p a r s e d .. etc`

Comment: sorry, i fixed it now. however it was an example and the actual regex is different than this one, so the problem is not regex.